# Join a square shaped div seamlessly with a circular shaped div

Tags: html, css

I built a progress bar that has "steps", which are joined by a bar (a div). As seen in the photo, I need to get the bar to join seamlessly into each "step". Is there a way to do this? E.g. via `::before` and `::after`, without introducing some serious positioning hacks?

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your HTML and CSS and what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `:after` pseudo-element little longer then space between each circle and then position it so that it goes under left and right circle.

If the margin is `20px` then you can create each line `44px` for example and set `right: 2px` so that there is `2px` of line under circles on both sides.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '';
  height: 15px;
  width: 44px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2px;
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Coloring is something that need a bit more attention.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
  border: thin solid gray;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #3f4c6b 0%,#c675c1 100%);
}

.bar-side {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}

.bar-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.bar {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  display: inline-block;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar-side">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">2</div>
  <div class="bar-middle">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">3</div>
  <div class="bar-side">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like your code has the same problem as mine. The end of the bar touches the circle at the bar's midpoint, but there is still a gap between the rest of the bar and the circle. But, adding a `bar` inside `bar-middle` is a very good idea. It can then be positioned relatively and adjusted slightly to the left and right to join into the circle seamlessly. Thanks for the inspiration!